# Locally countable implies countably tight?

Tags: general-topology

- Locally countable: The space has a base of open sets, each with countable cardinality.
- Countably tight: for each A⊆X and each $p\in\overline{A}$ there is a countable subset $D\subseteq A$ such that $p\in \overline D$.

Does locally countable imply countably tight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $p\in\overline{A}$, choose a countable basic open neighborhood $U$ of $p$. Then for every open neighborhood $V$ of $p$, $U\cap V$ is open and therefore intersects $A$, that is, $U\cap V\cap A$ is nonempty.

So let $D=A\cap U$. $D$ is countable, and for every open neighborhood $V$ of $p$, $V$ intersects $D=A\cap U$, since $D\cap V=U\cap V\cap A$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $p \in \overline{A}$ and $U$ is open containing $p$, then $p \in \overline{U \cap A}$. So if $U$ is chosen to be countable, $U \cap A$ is as required for showing countable tightness.